# yii unsecure attribute while using mimetypes file validation

Tags: validation, file-upload, yii, mime-types, runtime-error

i use the following mime type file validation

```
 array('image', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true,'mimeTypes'=>'image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png', 'on' => 'update')
```

works well if a file doesnt have the right mime type.
but if the validation is successful, the logg sais

```
2012/09/27 17:13:02 [warning] [application] unsafe Attribut "image" couldnt be set.
```

but it is defintily declared as save

```
array('image', 'safe', 'on' => 'update')
```

thats why i receive an error like this

```
finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\php3729.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
$mimeType=finfo_file($info,$file->getTempName());
```

seems, that the file cant be saved i its unsafe attribute.
the strange thing is, if i uncomment the validation rule with mimeTypes check, everthing works fine.

in my controller i set the image file like this

```
   if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            $user->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            $user->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($user, 'image');
            if ($user->validate()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you run `$user->image->saveAs($path)` before saving the whole model, that's why it's trying to validate your file in temporary folder when it is already moved to the $path.
So, use `$user->validate()` or run `saveAs($path)` after saving model.